# How to escape quotechar in opencsv CSVReader. Default quotechar is (") double quote

Tags: opencsv

The data which I am passing through CSV file contain text as - 1 Micron Filter Cartridge 10"-(DNL). I want to escape " in the text.

Comment: Standard CSV escaping replaces each single (`"`) quote with two quotes (`""`).

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSVReader with a RFC4180Parser and that will allow the data you listed above.

The default CSVReader uses a CSVParser and for that you need to use a \ character, unless you set a different escape character, to let the CSVParser know the quote is just another character in the string and not to be acted upon.

Hope that helps.

Scott :)